# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, database

I have deleted old theme column in database table "theme".
after that i am getting error on catalog view page and product view like this

```
 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( ' at line 7, query was: SELECT ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2) AS `min_price_expr` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='1872'
    LEFT JOIN `magento_catalogpermissions_index` AS `perm` ON perm.customer_group_id = 0 AND perm.category_id = cat_index.category_id AND perm.website_id = '1'
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_approval` ON (`at_approval`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_approval`.`attribute_id` = '261') AND (`at_approval`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_listing_fee` ON (`at_listing_fee`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_listing_fee`.`attribute_id` = '263') AND (`at_listing_fee`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5b863003f2f674_54776102` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `e`.`min_price` ASC
LIMIT 100
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( ' at line 7

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( ' at line 7, query was: SELECT ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2) AS `min_price_expr` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='1872'
LEFT JOIN `magento_catalogpermissions_index` AS `perm` ON perm.customer_group_id = 0 AND perm.category_id = cat_index.category_id AND perm.website_id = '1'
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_approval` ON (`at_approval`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_approval`.`attribute_id` = '261') AND (`at_approval`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_listing_fee` ON (`at_listing_fee`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_listing_fee`.`attribute_id` = '263') AND (`at_listing_fee`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5b863003f2f674_54776102` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `e`.`min_price` ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Again Restore theme column . As you must know that table structure of magento must not be altered.

You can delete content of column but you can't delete complete column.

Comment: i did this.. but still the issue is same

Answer (score 0):

its possible that catalog design or layout update might be using the theme you have deleted, thus you are seeing that error.

Right way to do it by [magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-uninstall.html)